# Combining two SQL queries that return different number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to combine two datasets (queries) into one dataset for an SSRS report. They both pass the same parameter for getting results but the problem is that they return a different number of results because you pass a string that contains IDs separated by a delimiter and each query returns results for all IDs passed in parameter.

First query is passed a parameter, for example, `@Sem_ID = '137210;137211'`

```
SELECT Sem_ID, Sem_KW, Sem_Jahr, Sem_SemNrKata, Sem_von, Sem_bis, h.chr_name, h.chr_ort
FROM acc_seminar.t_Seminar
JOIN dbo.tbl_hotel h ON Sem_Ht_ID=h.pk_hotel
WHERE Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '') AND (Sem_SemTh_ID != 76 AND Sem_Sto = 0)
```

which returns one row for each value in @Sem_ID: ID 137210 and ID 137211.

[image]

Second query passes the same parameter and returns multiple rows: for example, I get 7 rows in results: 5 for ID 137210 and 2 for ID 137211.

```
SELECT tu.TU_Name AS Name, tu.TU_Vorname AS Vorname, ParkgebuehrBrutto AS Preis
FROM acc_seminar.t_Teiluber_Ext tux
JOIN acc_seminar.t_Teiluber tu ON tux.TeiluberId = tu.TU_ID
JOIN acc_seminar.t_Seminar s ON tu.TU_Sem_ID = s.Sem_ID
WHERE s.Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
                   FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
                   WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
  AND ParkgebuehrBrutto IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

I need to somehow combine those queries so that I have one query that is passed in report.

I tried using UNION but number of columns differs in both queries. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your two datasets and the results of your queries?

Comment: @DKyleo sorry, forgot to include second query. Edited my question and added pics of results I get

Comment: `5 for ID 137210 and 2 for ID 137211.` and what is the logic of _combining_ 5 rows with 2? Please provide sample source data and desired output as DKyleo already asked.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I can't provide sample data as it contains real information I'm not allowed to share. The desired output I need is this: in my report I have separate dataset for seminar information (first query) and a separate dataset for attendees of the seminar (second query). I need to combine them into a single dataset so that I can show multiple grids for each seminar ID value I pass in Sem_ID.

Comment: Nobody wants your sensitive data. `(1, 2, 3), (4, 5) -> (1, 2, 3, NULL), (4, NULL, NULL, 5)` - something like that. `into a single dataset` what kind of dataset? How are we supposed to know how are _different_ dataset supposed to be "combined" into one? Union? Full join? Cross join + aggregation? Left join?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood you correctly.

```
-- query 1
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  col4,
  NULL col5 -- this column is not exist in the query 1
FROM ...

UNION ALL

-- query 2
SELECT
  NULL col1, -- this column is not exist in the query 2
  col2,
  col3,
  NULL col4, -- this column is not exist in the query 2
  col5
FROM ...
```

Your queries with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
  Sem_ID, Sem_KW, Sem_Jahr, Sem_SemNrKata, Sem_von, Sem_bis, h.chr_name, h.chr_ort,
  NULL Name, NULL Vorname, NULL Preis
FROM acc_seminar.t_Seminar
JOIN dbo.tbl_hotel h ON Sem_Ht_ID=h.pk_hotel
WHERE Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '') AND (Sem_SemTh_ID != 76 AND Sem_Sto = 0)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
  tu.TU_Name AS Name, tu.TU_Vorname AS Vorname, ParkgebuehrBrutto AS Preis
FROM acc_seminar.t_Teiluber_Ext tux
JOIN acc_seminar.t_Teiluber tu ON tux.TeiluberId = tu.TU_ID
JOIN acc_seminar.t_Seminar s ON tu.TU_Sem_ID = s.Sem_ID WHERE s.Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')  AND ParkgebuehrBrutto IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

One more variant how to combine two recordsets:

```
;WITH cte1 AS(
  SELECT Sem_ID, Sem_KW, Sem_Jahr, Sem_SemNrKata, Sem_von, Sem_bis, h.chr_name, h.chr_ort, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Sem_ID) N
  FROM acc_seminar.t_Seminar
  JOIN dbo.tbl_hotel h ON Sem_Ht_ID=h.pk_hotel
  WHERE Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
  FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
  WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '') AND (Sem_SemTh_ID != 76 AND Sem_Sto = 0)
),
cte2 AS(
  SELECT tu.TU_Name AS Name, tu.TU_Vorname AS Vorname, ParkgebuehrBrutto AS Preis, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY tu.TU_Name) N
  FROM acc_seminar.t_Teiluber_Ext tux
  JOIN acc_seminar.t_Teiluber tu ON tux.TeiluberId = tu.TU_ID
  JOIN acc_seminar.t_Seminar s ON tu.TU_Sem_ID = s.Sem_ID
  WHERE s.Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
                     FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
                     WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
    AND ParkgebuehrBrutto IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  cte1.Sem_ID, cte1.Sem_KW, cte1.Sem_Jahr, cte1.Sem_SemNrKata, cte1.Sem_von, cte1.Sem_bis, cte1.chr_name, cte1.chr_ort,
  cte2.Name,cte2.Vorname,cte2.Preis
FROM cte1
FULL JOIN cte2 ON cte1.N=cte2.N
ORDER BY ISNULL(cte1.N,cte2.N)
```

But I don't understand why do you not use two different datasets in your report?

Comment: Menshow thank you for you answer. The reason I need to combine multiple datasets into one dataset is because I have 4 different grids in my report that use data from different tables. What we to do is pass multiple ID values in a single string parameter and I've never done anything like that before in SSRS, especially multiple grids in one tablix row.

Comment: @Bernard Polman - Maybe subreports will help you. Try to use them. You can look at my demo project here - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kjp9tszjch452dg/AAA1rJDbqTAH_NEiGVTAK4b1a?dl=0
`TestData.sql` - the script to create a test database. `Report Project1` - demo SSRS project. `Image N.png` - also look at screenshots.